# why my fallback font-family css (arial) is being used instead of the primary

Tags: css

I am having a problem with my font-family css rules.

This is my rule:

```
font-family: "helvetica neue ultralight", Arial, serif;
```

What i don't understand is why the Arial font is taking over the font view.

When i take down the Arial like this:

```
font-family: "helvetica neue ultralight", serif;
```

it will show the halvetica font, but when i add it (like here) the Arial will take over.

As for my  understanding arial should be the fallback.

Comment: Show an example (HTML and CSS) where this happens. If you are using `@font-face`, say that and show that code too.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So, you have `font-family: "helvetica neue ultralight", Arial, serif;` and this allows the browser to use Arial if `helvetica neue ultralight` font is not found and if Arial is not found then serif is used.

Okay, if you use:

```
font-family: "helvetica neue ultralight", serif;
```

`helvetica` is used, why?

There's even serif font isn't available in the browser. So, all of them are not available in the browser, then you'll see `helvetica` is used as local machine font but not the font included in the browser.

To conclude, check for font existence, double check the path of the font you embed using @font-face.

Comment: The word `serif` denotes a browser-dependent serif font, so it always exists.